# Privileges to select on a view - Issue

Tags: oracle, permissions, schema, oracle-12c

I have two schemas: A and B.

A has one table with the name 'TEST'. B has created a view 'BASE' which does select on table 'TEST'.

Now I create another user C to which I grant, **select on the view 'BASE'**.

When the user C runs the following statement, he gets insufficient privileges error:

```
select * on B.BASE;
```

What privileges is required to select the contents of the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to grant `select` on the tables in schema `A` to the user `B` `WITH GRANT OPTION`.

From [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_9013.htm#BABGJCJA):

> To grant SELECT on a view to another user, either you must own all of
>   the objects underlying the view or you must have been granted the
>   SELECT object privilege WITH GRANT OPTION on all of those underlying
>   objects. This is true even if the grantee already has SELECT
>   privileges on those underlying objects.